# How to build a complex widget without blocking the UI rendering?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building a client for a website where users can post comments in a tree-like fashion. Currently, I'm using the following in order to display a loading bar until the comments are loaded.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
            future: fetchComments(this.storyId),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return LinearProgressIndicator();
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    final MissingRequiredKeysException myError = snapshot.error;
                    return Text('Error: ${myError.missingKeys}');
                  } else {
                    final api.Comment comment = snapshot.data;

                    return Expanded(child: Comment(comment.comments));
                  }
              }
            }
)
```

This works pretty well when there are around 200 comments, but when there are more than this the loading bar "hangs" for a noticeable amount of time.

I assume that building the `Comment` widget takes a significant amount of time since it can be deeply nested.

In order to avoid hanging the main thread, I've modified my code to do the widget creation inside an `Isolate`:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
            future: compute<int, Widget>(
                buildComments, this.storyId),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return LinearProgressIndicator();
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    final ArgumentError myError = snapshot.error;
                    return Text('Error: ${myError.message}');
                  } else {
                    final Widget comments = snapshot.data;

                    return comments;
                  }
              }
            },
          )
```

But this is even slower, the UI is blocked for twice the amount of time. I *suspect* that it might be caused by the data transfer between the isolate and the main isolate (which might happen in the main thread).

What would be a good way to solve this hanging issue?

I would like to make it as transparent as possible for the user (no loading animation when scrolling the list).

Comment: Note that I've now created a issue on the repo of flutter about this topic: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30987

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is working slowly because you load a lot of objects into memory. I suggest you make lazy loading of comments from firebase. First show user only first 20 comments and when he scrolls to the bottom show 20 more comments and so on.

Comment: I'm not using Firebase, I'm using a REST API. I can't easily do a lazy loading because the comment tree is nested, and it's not balanced at all.

Comment: You can balance it and set the position in each object. Then save in local database, and then get it with lazy loading

Comment: I'm not sure how I could "balance" it without breaking the layout. The only way that I see would be to stop using nested widgets, but instead have each comment (no matter the nesting level) be an element of the top `ListView`. I think it would make collapsing comment trees on touch significantly harder which is why I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

may i suggest that you dont use future builder and get 200 comments per request , as i am sure as you said parsing the data is main reason of hanging as after the async download is finished what happens is you try to parse the data which happens on main queue -not main thread- as flutter is single threaded , so can you show us how you parse the data.

Comment: The API only allows me to retrieve all the comments at once. Also, the parsing is very likely not the issue as evidenced by the second example where I use `compute()`.

Comment: if you are using async then it wouldn't lag for the response so i think the problem that you are parsing in the wrong way or not in the most efficient way so please show me how you do it.

Comment: Even if I were using the most inefficient way in the world, it's done entirely in a `compute()` so it should not affect the main thread which is used in order to draw the UI.